# How can I put a variable value into Zend_Config_Ini

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to get the value of a variable into an instance of Zend_Config_Ini.

For instance, if I knew the name in advance, I could do something like,

```
$config->name = $value;
```

But since I'm receiving the name at runtime, I want to do:

```
$config->$var = $value;
```

Is it possible? I tried and it doesn't work. Here's my try:

**update_settings.php**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['key'];
$new_value = $_POST['new_value'];

if ($name && $value) 
{
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini('_config/config.ini', null, array('skipExtends' => true, 'allowModifications' => true));

    // EDIT
    $config->$name = $new_value;

    $writer = new Zend_Config_Writer_Ini(array('config' => $config, 'filename' => 'config.ini'));

    $json['success'] = $writer->write()
}
?>
```

If anyone have been able to do it, please tell me how.

Comment: I would advice against doing anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible (assuming I understand your question). I'm guessing here slightly as you just say "it doesn't work" which isn't the best error message I've ever seen.

You must make sure that the config.ini file you reference exists and that you have the correct path to it. Something like this should work for you:-

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', null, array('skipExtends' => true, 'allowModifications' => true));
//The previous line doesn't look quite right in your example.
$testVariableName = 'test';
$testVariableValue = 'testing';
$config->$testVariableName = $testVariableValue;
var_dump($config->test);
```

Output:-

```
string 'testing' (length=7)
```

Comment: I will give you the bounty in about 12 hours, when the site will allow me to do it ;) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: I am too! After 7 months of bad answers!

Comment: Part of the reason you were getting poor answers is that you were asking the wrong question :) I edited your question to make a bit more sense.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, thank you for that! Now I understand a quite more the `Zend_Config_Ini` class ;) Hope that it will help me getting my Ask privilege back!

Comment: You may get some up votes for the question now that it is clearer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [isset <sup>PHP Manual</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function.

```
if (isset( $_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['value']) ) {

$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('../conf/config.ini',null,array('skipExtends' => true,     'allowModifications' => true));
    // EDIT
    $config->$_POST['id'] = $_POST['value'];
.
.
.
```

If `id` & `value` are not set you will get a:

```
Notice: Undefined index: ...
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the answer to whatever the question is, though it is good advice.

Comment: I don't think you can actaully do `$config->$_POST['id']`.  It should probably be `$config->{$_POST['id']}`.